# Raspberry Pi not reachable via its hostname in LAN

Tags: raspbian, networking, ssh

My Raspberry Pi is not discoverable via its hostname in my LAN.

I have a couple of other [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) machines in the LAN, and they are all pingable via their hostnames.

On my Raspberry Pi:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ hostname
raspberrypi
```

On another machine in the same LAN:

```
ping raspberrypi
ping: unknown host raspberrypi
```

Comment: Duplicate question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77189/debian-not-reachable-via-its-hostname-in-lan. Closed as off-topic as this is a general Linux networking issue, not related to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Why is it not releated to Raspberry Pi if I have an Odroid with Ubuntu 14.04, a MÎNIX with Debian and a virtual PC I boot with Ubuntu 15.10 in the same network without this issue? Only on my Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspian I have this issue since I upgraded to Jessie.

Comment: just as a side note, this will probably not affect most people out there reading this, but some people might have avahi installed and wondering why it's not working for them -> one possibility is that your network configuration doesn't support multicast.

Comment: @clamp Shouldn't it be `ping raspberrypi.local`, I think that the `.local` part is vital

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried doing a ping test using the IP address? If that works your problem is usually with resolving the name to an IP address.

There are many ways to fix this. You could

- Add an entry to your /etc/hosts file with your pi's static-ip and hostname
- Add a static reservation to your dhcp server and add a record to your local dns server (If your router supports it)
- Run a service like NIS, Avahi or Samba on your pi. The choice depends on the OS you are pinging from.

  - Windows clients will benefit from installing Samba.
  - OS/X clients will benefit from Avahi or Samba.
  - Linux clients will probably benefit from NIS or Samba depending on what is installed. I guess the Ubuntu computers use samba to advertise their hostnames.

Comment: yeah pinging via the ip is fine, but it does not have a static ip address.

Comment: What OS are you pinging the pi and ubuntu boxes from? If you are on a linux machine could you see what the value of `hosts:` is in your `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?

Comment: Thanks. I've solved mine via Samba. Samba will be useful at some point as its a bit easier to access files this way

Answer (score 81):

You have to use avahi-daemon (zeroconf) if you want to connect via a hostname instead of an IP address. From the Raspberry Pi documentation on *[RPi Advanced Setup](http://elinux.org/RPi_Advanced_Setup)*:

Install avahi with the following commands on the Raspberry Pi:

```
sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon
```

Update boot startup for avahi-daemon

```
sudo insserv avahi-daemon
```

Apply the new configuration with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/avahi-daemon restart
```

The Raspberry Pi should now be addressable from other machines as raspberrypi.local, for example:
**ssh pi@raspberrypi.local** or http://raspberrypi.local if you have HTTP service installed.

If you couldn't connect from Windows PCs via SSH probably you haven't installed the [Bonjour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)) service.

Get Bonjour for Windows: *[Download Bonjour Print Services for Windows v2.0.2](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL999)*. Just install it.

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Comment: Silly, just to let others know: in my case my home router (Pirelli Centro Grande) is handling dhcp for my LAN. I never had ssh or network issues with Raspian nor any other Linux in my LAN until I upgraded to Raspian Jessie. This automatically installed dhcpd and avahi. I had to remove both, avahi-daemon and isc-dhcpd-server to avoid dhcp and name server conflicts with my router. Now my Raspberry is available by its name again.

Comment: I had the same issue as @ShyRobbiani - disabling/removing avahi-daemon caused my rpi to be picked up on my home network as it did pre-Jessie.

Comment: Why does this just work on retropie? https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/SSH

Comment: 'insserv' isn't available on my raspbian... ?

Comment: @copa017 Not here either on my Raspbian Lite at least, but just `sudo apt-get install insserv`. Otherwise follow the instructions above. Tested and worked for me!

Comment: $ sudo insserv avahi-daemon
insserv: FATAL: service mountkernfs has to exists for service udev
insserv: FATAL: service mountdevsubfs has to exists for service hwclock
insserv: FATAL: service urandom has to exists for service networking
insserv: FATAL: service udev is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service raspi-config
insserv: exiting now!